# OpenCV #define type for Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using C++ and OpenCV. Now I want to define a certain `Mat` type (such as `CV_32FC3`) to be used by lots of Mats in my code.

To achieve this, I tried:

```
#define FLOW_TYPE CV_32FC3;

cv::Mat BaoOpticalFlow::initialize(cv::Mat & frame1, cv::Mat & frame2)
{
    cv::Mat flow = cv::Mat(frame1.rows, frame1.cols, FLOW_TYPE);
}
```

However, this causes errors

> expected a ')'
>
> expected an expression

Then I tried,

```
#define FLOW_TYPE CV_32FC3;

cv::Mat BaoOpticalFlow::initialize(cv::Mat & frame1, cv::Mat & frame2)
{
    int test = FLOW_TYPE;
    cv::Mat flow = cv::Mat(frame1.rows, frame1.cols, test);
}
```

Which works, but is ugly in my opinion.

I don't really understand why or how this works, and why the first snippet causes errors. I'm not a C++ expert, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the `;` at the end of the define. Your code must be:

```
#define FLOW_TYPE CV_32FC3

cv::Mat BaoOpticalFlow::initialize(cv::Mat & frame1, cv::Mat & frame2)
{
    cv::Mat flow = cv::Mat(frame1.rows, frame1.cols, FLOW_TYPE);
}
```

More nice if you remove at all the define like this:

```
constexpr auto FLOW_TYPE = CV_32FC3;

cv::Mat BaoOpticalFlow::initialize(cv::Mat & frame1, cv::Mat & frame2)
{
    cv::Mat flow = cv::Mat(frame1.rows, frame1.cols, FLOW_TYPE);
}
```

Comment: Great! That fixes it. Could you explain why `constexpr auto` would be better than using `#define`?

Comment: Also, do you know why it does work using `int test = FLOW_TYPE;` as a local variable?

Comment: @WouterFlorijn Because it expands to `int test = CV_32FC3;;` with double semicolon, but that's not an error. `cv::Mat flow = cv::Mat(frame1.rows, frame1.cols, CV_32FC3;);` is instead an error (note the semicolon after `CV_32FC3`)

Comment: a define is bad because it rawly replace things. `constexpr auto FLOW_TYPE = CV_32FC3;` instead define a new constant known at compile time. In this case is harder make mistakes

Answer (score 2):

You have an error because it expands to

```
cv::Mat flow = cv::Mat(frame1.rows, frame1.cols, CV_32FC3;);
```

which causes the error (note the semicolon after `CV_32FC3`).
With the local variable instead it expands to:

```
int test = CV_32FC3;;
```

with double semicolon, but that's not an error.

You can correct this defining without the semicolon:

```
#define FLOW_TYPE CV_32FC3
```

---

It would probably easier to directly define which kind of matrix you want to use, and use `Mat_<Tp>` for easier access (you don't need to use `.at<Tp>(...)` to access elements, but just the parentheses):

```
using FlowMat = cv::Mat3f;

cv::Mat BaoOpticalFlow::initialize(cv::Mat & frame1, cv::Mat & frame2)
{
    FlowMat flow(frame1.rows, frame1.cols);

    // or, to zero initialize
    // FlowMat flow = FlowMat::zeros(frame1.rows, frame1.cols); 

}
```

Or:

```
using FlowType = cv::Vec3f;
using FlowMat = cv::Mat_<FlowType>;

void foo(cv::Mat& frame1, cv::Mat& frame2)
{
    FlowMat flow = FlowMat::zeros(frame1.rows, frame1.cols);

    flow(2, 3) = FlowType(1, 2, 3);
    FlowType value = flow(2, 3);

    // ...
}
```